# tab dissapears from fragmenttabhost after translation

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am using FragmentTabHost to create tabs.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tabwidget);
        // mTabHost = new FragmentTabHost(this);
        // mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(),
        // R.id.menu_settings);
        mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);
        Resources res = getResources();
        // first tab
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("key", url1);
        mTabHost.addTab(
                mTabHost.newTabSpec("vipusk").setIndicator(getTabIndicator(0)),
                VypuskTabFragment.class, b);
        // second tab
        b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("key", url2);
        TabSpec newTab = mTabHost.newTabSpec("constructor");
        newTab.setIndicator((getTabIndicator(1)));
        mTabHost.addTab(newTab, ConstructorTabFragment.class, b);
        // third tab
        b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("key", url3);
        mTabHost.addTab(
                mTabHost.newTabSpec("popular").setIndicator(getTabIndicator(2)),
                PopularTabFragment.class, b);
        // forth tab
        b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("key", url4);
        mTabHost.addTab(
                mTabHost.newTabSpec("actual").setIndicator(getTabIndicator(3)),
                ActualTabFragment.class, b);
        mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(tabChanged);
        DisplayImageOptions defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .cacheInMemory(true).cacheOnDisk(true).build();
        ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(
                getApplicationContext()).defaultDisplayImageOptions(
                defaultOptions).build();
        ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config); // Do it on Application start
    }
```

then at somepoint in tab fragment i call another

```
Fragment details = new Fragment1();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction();

                Bundle bundles = new Bundle();
                bundles.putSerializable("key", articles.get(position).getLink()
                        + "?templateStyle=19");
                details.setArguments(bundles);
                transaction.replace(android.R.id.content, details);
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit();
```

after that transation my tabwidget disapears. As i understand, type of transaction which i perform replace whole fragmenttabhost rather than content of individual tab. How can i avoid such behaviour?

edit:
if i replace

```
transaction.replace(android.R.id.content, details);
```

by

```
  transaction.replace(R.id.realtabcontent, details);
```

i will get desired behaviour, but on back navigation ill have to reload previous fragment again, whichi is not desired

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error was cause by replacment of top level fragment. Insted in tab fragment make extra container and use it for content fragments replacments